# CABasicAnimation CGRect enlarging not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cgrect, cabasicanimation

I am trying to use a CABasicAnimation in order to make a view larger and then smaller, using the autoreverse. I have QuartzCore imported. I am using the code below:

```
    CABasicAnimation *enlarge = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"enlargeKeyPath"];
    CGRect currentSize = CGRectMake(20, 27, _moveView.bounds.size.width, _moveView.bounds.size.height);
    CGRect newSize = CGRectMake(20, 27, 45, 46);
    enlarge.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:currentSize];
    enlarge.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:newSize];
    enlarge.autoreverses = YES;
    enlarge.repeatCount = 3.0;
    enlarge.duration = 0.5;
    [_moveView.layer addAnimation:enlarge forKey:@"enlargeKeyPath"];
```

However, that code does not work. Could someone help?

I feel like something is wrong with the keys for the animationWithKeyPath at the beginning and the forKey and the end. I don't know what those are used for. Could somebody help? Thanks!

Comment: Try a key path of "frame" with the code you're using.  Alternatively, since the origin doesn't change, you could animate "frame.size" from CGSize(45, 46) to _moveView.bounds.size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of "enlargeKeyPath", what we need here is actually `transform.scale`; as a result, we would animate the scaling as follows:

```
CABasicAnimation *enlarge = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"];
enlarge.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(3.0f, 3.0f, 1.0f)];
//To value is the value we wish your view to be scaled up (or down) to.
enlarge.autoreverses = YES;
enlarge.repeatCount = 3.0;
enlarge.duration = 0.5;
[_moveView.layer addAnimation:enlarge forKey:@"enlargeKeyPath"];
```

If you really would like to scale on the frame, we should use the keyPath `bounds` instead of `frame` as mentioned.

Thus, your code would be:

```
CABasicAnimation *enlarge = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"bounds"];
CGRect currentSize = CGRectMake(20, 27, _moveView.bounds.size.width, _moveView.bounds.size.height);
CGRect newSize = CGRectMake(20, 27, 45, 46);
enlarge.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:newSize];
enlarge.autoreverses = YES;
enlarge.repeatCount = 3.0;
enlarge.duration = 0.5;
[_moveView.layer addAnimation:enlarge forKey:@"enlargeKeyPath"];
```

For other values of keyPath that you could use, please refer to the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Key-ValueCodingExtensions/Key-ValueCodingExtensions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH12-SW8).

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```
CABasicAnimation *enlarge = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"bounds.size"];
CGSize currentSize = _moveView.bounds.size;
CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(_moveView.bounds.size.height * 1.5, _moveView.bounds.size.width * 1.5);
enlarge.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGSize:currentSize];
enlarge.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGSize:newSize];
enlarge.autoreverses = YES;
enlarge.repeatCount = INFINITY;
enlarge.duration = 5.0;
[_moveView.layer addAnimation:enlarge forKey:@"enlargeKeyPath"];
```

The basic problem you're encountering is confusing the animated key path (the parameter to `animationWithKeyPath:`) and the animation key (the parameter to `addAnimation:forKey:`

`animationWithKeyPath:` takes as a parameter the key path of an attribute of the view which will be animated.  To animate the bounds of a view you can use "bounds", likewise you could use "bounds.origin" or "bounds.size"

`addAnimation:forKey:` takes as a parameter a key which allows you to identify this particular animation in the future.